# Estou Começando no VBA, vocês podem me ajudar?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

Eu preciso fazer um código que quando eu clique em um botão (na planilha "MARC"), ele copie as informações na linha(que seria uma variável) e das colunas A até G, e leve até uma outra planilha com o nome "PROGR. DIARIA", procure a ultima linha e cole na primeira linha vazia depois da ultima linha com dados, vou deixar o que tentei fazer aqui

```
Sub Linha3_MARC()    
'   
' Linha3_MARC Macro   
'   
'

    Range("A3:G3").Select 
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("PROGR. DIARIA").Select            
    Range("A2").Select     
    Selection.End(xlDown).Select        
    ActiveSheet.Paste  
End Sub
```

Mas eu não consigo fazer eles pular mais uma linha depois do `selection.end(xldown).select`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bom dia Lucas,

O código abaixo deve resolver seu problema. Basicamente, eu criei duas variáveis para manipular as duas abas e uma variável que armazena qual foi a última linha com valores preenchidos na aba "PROG.DIARIA".

Eu não inseri nenhuma estrutura de repetição, pois, pela descrição do problema, não pareceu precisar.

O que faltava no código para pular a linha era o "Offset", o qual movimenta o cursor pela planilha.

```
Dim W           As Worksheet
Dim WB          As Worksheet
Dim UltCel      As Range

Set W = Sheets("MARC")
Set WB = Sheets("PROGR. DIARIA")

W.Select

'Seleciona o intervalo de A3:G3 na aba MARC e copia os valores
W.Range("A3:G3").Select
Selection.Copy

WB.Select
WB.Range("A2").Select
Set UltCel = WB.Cells(WB.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)

WB.Range("A" & UltCel.Row).Select
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
WB.Paste

'Volta para a planilha inicial
W.Select
W.Range("A3").Select

msgbox "Pronto"
```

Apenas uma dúvida: o que você quis dizer com "...na linha(que seria uma variável)..."?

Eu mantive a "cópia e cola" da aba "MARC" fixa no intervalo "A3:G3", porque, pelo o que eu vi, nessa aba, não teria mais linhas abaixo ou acima para copiar e colar. Se tiver, responda aqui que eu mudo o código.

Espero que ajude!

Comment: Boa tarde, desculpa a demora kk mas olha, peguei esse código e alterei algumas coisas e deu tudo certo, obrigado pela ajuda